# How to handle missing service class when binding to it?

Tags: android, service

I want to create an application which supports plugins. The plugins would be services implementing a specific AIDL interface. I would find the plugins using the package manager (they have a specific intent filter).

However I found a use case which I cannot handle: if a service is declared in the AndroidManifest, but the service class is missing (i.e. no java class matching the name), there is no way I can detect this. The call to Context.bindService will succeed (will return true), but none of the callbacks in the ServiceConnection will be called.

If I call startService before, or use the BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag, I can see in the log that it starts the process, but then it crashes. However I still won't get any callback about that in my process. Is there any nice solution to this problem? I would really like to avoid a timed wait.